# Einstein summation notation and multi indices

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, soft-question, definition, tensors

Consider the Einstein summation notation $A^{ij}B_{ij}$. I know that this summation takes over a each pair of indices $i,j$ and there is no confusion if they are tensors and the indexing sets are finite sets.

It seems to me when the addition (the summation) is not commutative or the indexing sets are  infinite set.
Then in general,
$$\sum_i\sum_{j} A^{ij}B_{ij} \neq \sum_{j}\sum_{i} A^{ij}B_{ij}$$ does't hold for infinite sums.

Edited: (to focus on one problem)

> Is Einstein summation notation defined only for tensors and finite sums?

Comment: this $\sum_i\sum_{j} A^{ij}B_{ij} \neq \sum_{j}\sum_{i} A^{ij}B_{ij}$ never can happen, as $+$ is a commutative operation.

Comment: Wrong. With infinite sums you cannot necessarily change the order of summation. But this has nothing to do with contraction of tensors or Einstein.

Comment: @Masacroso for real number, + is commutative, but for infinite sums, $\sum_i\sum_{j} A^{ij}B_{ij} \neq \sum_{j}\sum_{i} A^{ij}B_{ij}$ can happen

Comment: @Tim I'm assuming from the beginning that the sum is finite, as it seems a finite dimensional problem of physics

Comment: @Masacroso Sorry for my unclear statement, I have edited to make it better.

Comment: Whether a sum is finite or infinite (Einstein notation or not) should always be clear from the context.